# Getting a message that says "Option strict on disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Integer'."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, syntax-error, basic

I'm new to the programming world and I have ran across an error I have not seen yet that says "Option strict on disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Integer'." I followed my textbook word for word and everything seems correct but i still get this message. It would be really appreciated if someone could help me understand whats going on a bit better.

```
Private Sub BtnDiveCost_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDiveCost.Click
    ' This event determines the cost and displays the size of the dive team, the cost, and the lenght of the dive

    Dim intTeamSize As Integer
    Dim blnNumberInTeamIsValid As Boolean = False
    Dim blnDiveIsSelected As Boolean = False
    Dim intDiveChoice As Integer
    Dim strSelectedTeam As String = ""
    Dim intLocationChoice As Integer
    Dim intLength As Integer = 0
    Dim decTotalCost As Decimal

    ' Calls a function to ensure the number of people in the dive team is valid
    blnNumberInTeamIsValid = ValidateNumberInTeam()
    ' Call a function to ensure a scuba dive was selected
    intDiveChoice = ValidateDiveSelection(blnDiveIsSelected, strSelectedTeam) '<-- Error occurs here.

    ' If Number Of people And the dive trip are valid, calculate the cost
    If (blnNumberInTeamIsValid And blnDiveIsSelected) Then
        intTeamSize = Convert.ToInt32(TxtTeam.Text)
        intLocationChoice = CboLocation.SelectedIndex
        Select Case intLocationChoice
            Case 0
                decTotalCost = AustraliaDiveCost(intDiveChoice, intTeamSize, intLength)
            Case 1
                decTotalCost = BelizeDiveCost(intDiveChoice, intTeamSize, intLength)
            Case 2
                decTotalCost = FijiDiveCost(intDiveChoice, intTeamSize, intLength)
        End Select
        ' Display cost of the scuba dive
        LblScubaDive.Text = "Dive: " & strSelectedTeam
        LblCost.Text = "Cost: " & decTotalCost.ToString("C")
        LblLength.Text = "Length: " & intLength.ToString() & "hours"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The second parameter of `ValidateDiveSelection` accepts `Integer` while you're passing a string. You need to use either `Integer.Parse()`, `Integer.TryParse()` or `Convert.ToInt32()` if the string only contains numeric value. Note that `Option Strict On` enforces explicit string-to-numeric conversion.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto It would appear from how `ValidateDiveSelection` is called that it is supposed to accept a string, validate it and return an integer if valid. So the problem must be that `ValidateDiveSelection`'s second parameter is not declared as string.

Comment: As an aside, it appears that your textbook uses "Apps Hungarian" for naming variables; this is widely considered to be poor style (and tends to make me a little suspicious of the quality / currentness of the text).